# Passing parameters to eventFilter for QLineEdit Qt

Tags: qt, events, event-handling

I have a QLineEdit which I set an eventFilter using installEventFilter(this). Is it possible to pass in parameters to this eventFilter? For example, I want multiple QLineEdits to all call the same eventFilter, but I need to pass in a parameter in order to be able to tell which QLineEdit box caused the event to occur.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of event? You usually don't "call the eventFilter", but events occur that are dispatched via the event system and are passed through eventFilter().

Answer (score 1):

The sender object is already passed to eventFilter as first parameter. So you are able to determine which QLineEdit is dispatched like this:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev) {
    if (obj == lineEdit1) {
        // event from lineEdit1
    } else if (obj == lineEdit2) {
        // event from lineEdit2
    }
}
```